# Strange console output when starting app: "Forcing GfxDevice: Null"

Tags: unity-game-engine, mono

My Unity app is successfully built, but it's not working.
I always see the strange console output below after the app starts.
What's going wrong?

```
Mono path[0] - 'E:/Mvp/New Unity Project (6)_Data/Managed'
Mono config path - 'E:/Mvp/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
Initialize engine version: 2019.2.15f1 (dcb72c2e9334)
[XR] Discovering subsystems at path E:/Mvp/New Unity Project (6)_Data/UnitySubsystems
Forcing GfxDevice: Null
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=0
NullGfxDevice:
    Version:  NULL 1.0 [1.0]
    Renderer: Null Device
    Vendor:   Unity Technologies
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
- Completed reload, in 0.059 seconds
UnloadTime: 0.415900 ms
```

[image]

Comment: that looks like unity isn't finding your graphics device, do you use -batchmode by any chance?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like server build.
In your build setting menu, do you have the "Server Build" checkbox checked? 
If yes, un-check that and retry.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a symptom of the same problem described here:
["Shader Unsupported" when starting Unity server with -batchmode -nographics flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67523467/shader-unsupported-when-starting-unity-server-with-batchmode-nographics-flag/75047542#75047542)

For Unity 2021: make sure you dont have Dedicated Server selected in the Build Settings. This can also happen when you simply take a look at the Dedicated Server Settings tab in the Player settings.