# Unity MLAPI server runs at 100% CPU

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a Unity game with their new **MLAPI** (Mid-level networking API). I've followed [this tutorial](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/docs/tutorials/helloworldtwo/index.html) exactly without changing anything, and the game is running fine on my local (Linux) PC.

I changed the connection IP and copied the build file over to a cloud server I rent (DigitalOcean Ubuntu 20.04), and used the flag `-mlapi server`, and the `-batchmode -nographics` options, but I still suspect it is trying to emulate graphics on the CPU.

The 100% CPU problem seems to be [documented](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/index.html#server-build-is-using-100-cpu) and the suggested solution is including the line `Application.targetFrameRate = 30;`. I tried doing the following (`targetFrameRate` is ignored if vSync is not disabled):

```
switch (mlapiValue)
{
    case "server":
        netManager.StartServer();
        // https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting
        QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 0;
        Application.targetFrameRate = 1;
        break;
    case "host":
        netManager.StartHost();
        break;
    case "client":
        netManager.StartClient();
        break;
}
```

However, when I move the client, I still get 100% CPU (with of course the additional bonus of each action being executed instantly on the server(!?) but 1 second later on each client).

What is even going on here? Someone online suggested it might be related to socket polling, but when I start 2 instances one of them gets killed (out of CPU). Note that the single server still seems pretty responsive.

Comment: Considering profilers is not well written for linux+core, I suggest you to use AppMetrics. This way you can at least diagnose performance drops by hand. We use it for containered apps to diagnose what cause performance spikes at server side.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am using `htop`, not the built-in Unity profiler.

Comment: It's an empty scene with 2 objects in it, just as described in the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

**This issue only seems to occur on Linux machines with exactly 1 core.** I tried reducing fps to 1 on a single-core, which *did* reduce CPU below 5%, but only if I start a single server (e.g. on port 7778). Once I start a second server on port 7779, we are back at 100% CPU. In summary:

| Setup | Outcome |
| --- | --- |
| 1 core, 60 fps, 1 instance | 100% CPU (bad) |
| 1 core, 1 fps, 1 instance | <5% CPU (OK) |
| 1 core, 1 fps, 2 instances | 100% CPU (bad) |
| 2 cores, 60 fps, 10+ instances | <10% CPU (OK) |

So my recommendation is to just rent a cloud instance with 2+ vCPUs.